# Changed admin url from index.php/admin to somthing else don't remember it

Tags: admin, admin-panel, dashboard

changed my admin url from index.php/admin to something else don't remember it. Can anyone tell me how to get back into my dashboard.

Comment: Where did you change it? You should find it in app/etc/local.xml

Comment: in magento community. I use godaddy to host. trying to find it in there but no luck.

Comment: Can you explain how you changed the link to admin?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40620/correct-way-to-change-the-magento-1-9-admin-url/40622#40622

Answer (score 2):

You can change the admin url in:

1. As @brentwpeterson wrote in `app/etc/local.xml`:

   `<admin>
       <routers>
           <adminhtml>
               <args>
                   <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
               </args>
           </adminhtml>
       </routers>
   </admin>`
2. In the `admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Admin Base URL -> Use Custom Admin URL / Use Custom Admin Path`. But if you changed it there and can't login in the admin panel you should revert it in the database. The SQL queries are:

`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'admin/url/use_custom';`
`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'admin/url/use_custom_path';`