# I made a change to my Admin URL in SYSTEM CONFIGURATION

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I changed the URL of my store but made no other changes, now the Admin url is not working.

How do I get my admin panel working again?

I am working in a test website, and the version of Magento is 1.9.1.1.

Comment: how you change store url ?? using system->configuration ??

Comment: When you try to open admin, What error you face?

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/40622/45103

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to this section here:

[image]

In order to revert this, you will need to access your database, more specifically the table "core_config_data". You would access this through PHPmyAdmin or SequelPro.

In "core_config_data". Search for a path called:

```
admin/url/use_custom
```

It would be a "1". Change that to a "0". Manually clear the cache. You should be able to see the admin page now. If you cannot, most likely more configurations have been changed and will need to be reverted.